# Java api for mac environment

Tags: java, macos

I’m wondering if there are native java api (jars) for mac that allows to get details on a process that opened a socket to my process.

The scenario:

1. I’m running my process (a daemon) on the same machine as the process that I need to get details on.
2. I have the details of the socket of the remote process that opened a connection to me.
3. I want to get the pid and the client binary (jar run by JVM, regular OS binary and others) information, such as:
   a. PID
   b. Path
   c. OS user running the process.

I can perform this action by lsof but I prefer to use a Java solution.

Added: I know that other vendors created specific Java libraries for specific platforms.

Thanks!

Comment: This is so platform dependent that you really are better of using lsof